# How to print certain elements from vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, filter

I am trying to print out whatever is necessary from my program. What it does is it takes a long list from a text file and sort it based on first choice and GPA and put it into a vector. I manage to sort by First choice and GPA however how can I remove whatever output that isn't necessary?

This is an example of my Txt File (The sequence of each line is 1st choice, 2nd choice, 3rd choice, GPA, Name):

```
CC,DR,TP,3.8,AlexKong
SN,SM,TP,4,MarcusTan
DR,TP,SC,3.6,AstaGoodwin
SC,TP,DR,2.8,MalcumYeo
SN,SM,TP,3.7,DavidLim
SN,SM,TP,3.2,SebastianHo
SC,TP,DR,4,PranjitSingh
DR,TP,SC,3.7,JacobMa
and so on...
```

This is my output now (it is a long vector):

```
TP,DR,SC,4,SitiZakariah
TP,DR,SC,3.9,MuttuSami
TP,DR,SC,3.5,SabrinaEster
TP,DR,SC,3,KarimIlham
TP,DR,SC,3,AndryHritik
SN,SM,TP,4,MarcusTan
SN,SM,TP,3.8,MarcusOng
SN,SM,TP,3.7,DavidLim
SN,SM,TP,3.4,MollyLau
SN,SM,TP,3.2,SebastianHo
SN,SM,TP,3.2,NurAfiqah
SN,SM,TP,2.4,TanXiWei
SC,TP,DR,4,SallyYeo
SC,TP,DR,4,PranjitSingh
SC,TP,DR,3.6,RanjitSing
SC,TP,DR,2.8,MalcumYeo
SC,TP,DR,2.8,AbdulHalim
SC,TP,DR,2.7,AlifAziz
DR,TP,SC,3.9,SitiAliyah
DR,TP,SC,3.9,LindaChan
DR,TP,SC,3.8,SohLeeHoon
DR,TP,SC,3.7,PrithikaSari
DR,TP,SC,3.7,NurAzizah
DR,TP,SC,3.7,JacobMa
DR,TP,SC,3.6,AstaGoodwin
CC,DR,TP,3.9,MuruArun
CC,DR,TP,3.8,AlexKong
CC,DR,TP,3.7,DamianKoh
CC,DR,TP,3.3,MattWiliiams
CC,DR,TP,3.3,IrfanMuhaimin
```

And this is the output that I need (Basically students with CC as their 1st choice without displaying the 3 options):

```
3.9,MuruArun
3.8,AlexKong
3.7,DamianKoh
3.3,MattWiliiams
3.3,IrfanMuhaimin
```

This is my program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct greater
{
    template<class T>
    bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) const { return a > b; }
};

void main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    int p = 0;
    ifstream File;
    File.open("DSA.txt");
    if (!File.is_open()) return;

    string First;

    cout << "Round 1:\n";
    
        while (File >> First)
        {
            v.push_back(First);
            p++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
        {
            sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater());

            cout << v[i] << endl;
        }
}
```

Comment: split the row, and filter those who didnt have CC in the 1st selection

Comment: Hint: [`copy_if`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56027849/how-can-i-filter-an-array-in-c).

Comment: You should sort the `v` once, outside the loop. It doesn't change anything after the first sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your last for loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
 {
     sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater());
     cout << v[i].substr(9) << endl;
 }
```

EDIT:
If you want to only display ones with CC as 1st choice you can add if statement to your loop:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
 {
     if (v[i].substr(0,2) != "CC") continue; 
     cout << v[i].substr(9) << endl;
 }
```

Also, I noticed another problem in your code. You should not sort the vector at every iteration. You should do it only once before the loop:

```
 sort(v.begin(), v.end(), greater()); 
 for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
 {
     if (v[i].substr(0,2) != "CC") continue; 
     cout << v[i].substr(9) << endl;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for this but how do I only print out ones with CC as 1st choice and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 0):

as I propose in the comment,
since the data is well defined as a structure, you can interpret semantically each row and filter according to that: here is what am talking about

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    std::string r = "CC,DR,TP,3.9,MuruArun";
    std::string delimiter = ",";
    std::string token = r.substr(0, r.find(delimiter));
    if(token == ??)// compare to what ever you want 
    {
        v.emplace_back(r);
    }

    cout << "token: " << token << endl; 
    cout << v.size() << endl; 
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what is the '?' for? what do you mean by compare to whatever I want